# How to create a web application in .Net that generates a sub-domain URL for each user of the website at run time

Tags: .net, iis-7, url-rewriting, saas, wildcard-subdomain

Hello Technical People,

I am planning to create a Web Application using ***SaaS*** model .

For that, I want to develop application in such a way that the application should create a Unique sub-domain URL for each of the website user at run time like:

if the website is 
    **www.mydomain.com** then
it should create sub-domain URLs i.e. 
    **www.user1.mydomain.com for User1**
and 
     **www.user2.mydomain.com for User2** and so on at run time.

The website will be created using .NET framework 4.0 & Sql server 2008
The hosting environment will be IIS 7.0.

About this i have some idea that i need to use URL rewriting with Wild Card domain facility activated on IIS 7.0 for the web application.

But, The actual process to activate Wild Card domain facility on IIS and the Piece of code to display user specific sub-domain url is not cleared to me.

An early response will be appreciated.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Take all the Binding info ie(ip address,hostname,application pool) from user.

**Step 2:** Check whether the websitename is already exist in your IIS, if Yes then you have to give a unique name.

**Step 3:** Create a new site in IIS with all the binding info.

I did the same task earlier with also create the new fresh database on every new site creation.